# In Google Form how to replace an extract value by a text?

Tags: javascript, google-forms

How can i replace a value from a google form by a specified text ?
For example :

Q1 : Did you sleep well ?
A) yes
B) No

-------> If A "The subject say he sleep well" if B "......" as response for this question.

Ive try this kind of trick at the form submission :

```
function onFormSubmit() {
docReplace();
}

function docReplace() {

var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
// change
body.replaceText("Yes", "A new text");

}
```

Thanks for your help !

Sebastien.

Comment: we're gonna need to see some context code

Comment: I just try to understand how to replace a specified string by another before the google form submission. If soemeone have an exemple i can adapt. thanks !

Comment: Think there is some clue here: https://madebymany.com/blog/supercharge-your-google-form-with-google-apps-script but i cannot adapt it...

Comment: There is no way to intercept a Form submission and modify the answer before the data is written to the Form or a spreadsheet.  You can change the value in a spreadsheet afterwards, but I don't know of anyway to edit the data in the Form without opening up the Form again.

Comment: Thx. I use form publisher to generate automates pdf report...so the goal is to modify theses values in the sheet before the doc generation.

Comment: ...so the goal is to modify theses values in the sheet before the doc generation. So can i apply automate function to my sheet that changes somes strings by other values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found no way to modify the anwsers before the submitting process. For now, based on the awnsers in my sheet, im using a script in Google Docs to modify the texts of my report document.